# Requirement to work with same employer "passport talent"

Tags: france

My wife was on a dependent visa with me in France. Since I left France, she has gotten her  own "Talent Passport – Qualified employee". At this point she has been in France for 4.5 years.

Now "normally" one can only work with the the employer with whom they got the work permit for the first 2 years and only then are free to switch. However, given that she was already in the country for 4.5 years and has been with her current employer for more than 1 year already, what are the rules in her case? Also note that since she did not come from a foreign country her employer has not had to pay anything for the process.

Reference:
https://www.welcometofrance.com/en/fiche/graduates-talent-passport

Comment: I have trouble tracking down all the references but it seems it wouldn't make a difference. The two-year limit is relative to the “issuance of the permit” and not the time in France or how long you have been working for the same employer.

Comment: So a related question is what happens if there is a rupture conventionelle in those two years. My wife has already worked for more than 2 years and is thus elligible for 2 years of chomage. Does it mean that the government essentially wants her to keep taking chomage without looking for another job?

Comment: Interesting question, I don't know the answer but there are several issues to consider. First, the general rule doesn't apply if you lose your job involuntarily so, in general, the government does want people losing their job while on a *passeport talent* to look for a job (I guess that's why you bring up the *rupture conventionnelle* as an corner case). Second, a *rupture conventionnelle* has to be approved by the DREETS. If it looks like it is designed to circumvent the rules (in that case, the rule that ARE recipients are required to look for a job), I guess they might refuse.